# Visual Studio detects dependency cycle which does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependencies

So I was writing tests for my system. My system consists out of various layers within the context of a clean architecture. My Core project contains services, these services have tests. When I started writing theses tests everything went fine. But as I saw that the test project was not in the designated **tests** folder, I moved it. After this Visual Studio started talking about a cycle. First let me shed some light on the projects that should have these cycles; according to Visual Studio.

- API Project (API -> Core)
- Core (Core -> Shared)
- API.Tests (API.Tests -> API)
- Core.Tests (Core.Tests -> Core)

The above points are according to what I implemented, and to how the solution explorer shows project dependencies. Visual studio is giving the following exception:

[image]

However, there is nothing in the Core project which has a reference to Api.Tests.

[image]

[image]

Below is the Core.csproj file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

API Project reference:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Core\Core.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Infrastructure\Infrastructure.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

API.Tests project reference:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\API\API.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

What is causing this cycle, am I missing something here, is there more information required?

Comment: And there isn't a reference to API.Tests in Shared?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama No, but there was a reference to API in Shared and Infrastructure (I did not do this myself, this happened after placing a test project as I said before). I really think something went wrong with Visual Studio itself perhaps

Comment: Perhaps you chose an option using the refactoring tools one time and it helpfully added a reference for you. It has happened to me before. :(

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama you might be correct. I always use the "add reference to" to add like the project references. And a few moments before my intellisense threw an exception (whilst mocking expressions). And also replaced an entire project after. Maybe it's a result of all these events combined. Very odd still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I "fixed" the problem. But I can not determine the exact cause. However, I can tell what happened and what I changed. The mistake might be something @ProgrammingLlama indicated, not sure.

I created a test project in, according to VS, the **tests** folder. This project was named **Core.Tests**. When I checked the project directory I noticed that something went wrong. The **Core.Tests** was not placed in the corresponding **tests** folder. So naturally I moved it to the **tests** folder.

Once the project had been moved, exceptions came to light. Exceptions about a cycle that actually did not exist. There are two other projects: **Infrastructure** and **Shared**. **These two projects, completely randomly, had a reference to the API project** (which makes no sense in my chosen architecture). And I also did not do this myself. So something - small suspicion in the comments - went wrong. I fixed it by removing these API references.

I guess the only conclusion I can make is that, when such a situation occurs, just check projects for bad references (like references that don't belong there). Might as well check all the project references just to be sure.

I basically fixed it by checking the project references, and then proceeded to fix them. Now everything works again.